# XDG autostart order - how to control it?

Tags: systemd, xfce, .desktop, autostart, xdg

When logging into my XFCE session, there are several "things" started via the XDG autostart mechanism. Is it possible to control the order in which applications start, or having some sort of priority settings? How?

For example, in `/etc/xdg/autostart` there's both *pulseaudio.desktop* and *pasystray.desktop* and the latter takes several seconds to load. How can I make sure that pulseaudio is started before pasystray?

Answer (score 0):

Edit file with pasystray.desktop
In line starting with Exec= write:
Exec=sh -c "sleep 14; pasystray &" &
14 are second to delay before load pasystray. Change as you wish

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).